# Não consigo resolver a questão da obi distanciamento entre amigos

Tags: python-3.x

eu fiz um progama simples para resolver um exercicio da obi mais toda vez que a obi corrigir o
progama  da erro por favor alguém pode corrigir.

link do exercicio: https://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/p1/2019/f1/amigos/

```
 N = int(input())
lista = []
maxi = []
for r in range(0,N):
    i = int(input())
    if i == 0:
        lista.append(i+1)
    else:
        lista.append(i)
contl = -1
contg = 0
while contg < N+1:
    for r in range(0,N-1):
        S = lista[0+contg]+lista[contl] + N+contl
        maxi.append(S)
        contl -= 1   
    contl = -1  
    contg += 1  
    N = N - 1
resul = max(maxi)
print(resul)
```

erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código e demais mensagens como texto. Colocá-los como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052). É interessante também trazer o enunciado para cá, pois as perguntas não podem depender de links externos (eles podem servir de complemento, mas [a pergunta deve ter toda a informação necessária](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6252/112052))

Answer (score 1):

Esta questão se refere ao problema **Distância entre amigos** disponibilizada pela OBI de 2019 e. posteriormente, disponibilizada pelo site **URI Online Judge** com o mesmo título e com a numeração **3050** da categoria **AD-HOC**.

Veja [Aqui](https://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/p1/2019/f1/amigos/) a íntegra do enunciado disponibilizado pelo site da **OBI** e, se preferir, veja [Aqui](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/3050) a íntegra do enunciado disponibilizado pelo site **URI** - que por sinal é o mesmo.

Para resolvermos esta questão devemos levar em considerações algumas coisas.

Em primeiro lugar devemos capturar de forma correta os valores. A captura correta dos valores é:

```
n = int(input())
p = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

Observe que **n** é a quantidade de valores que serão digitados no próximo input.
No próximo input deveremos inserir **exatamente** a quantidade de valores especificado anteriormente.

Depois disso devemos calcular a distância correta entre o prédio e o último andar do prédio 0. Para isso devemos implementar o seguinte laço de repetição:

```
dist = 0
k = -1
for i in range(n):
    d = p[0] + i + p[i]
    if d > dist:
        dist = d
        k = i
```

E por fim, devemos calcular a posição do amigo mais distante do último andar do prédio K. Para isso devemos implementar outro laço de repetição:

```
max_dist = 0
for j in range(n):
    if j != k:
        max_dist = max(max_dist, p[k] + abs(k - j) + p[j])

print(max_dist)
```

Observe que nesta última etapa estamos calculando a máxima distância entre os amigos.

O código completo ficaria:

```
n = int(input())
p = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

dist = 0
k = -1
for i in range(n):
    d = p[0] + i + p[i]
    if d > dist:
        dist = d
        k = i

max_dist = 0
for j in range(n):
    if j != k:
        max_dist = max(max_dist, p[k] + abs(k - j) + p[j])

print(max_dist)
```

Só para constar, esta questão já foi **testada**, **submetida** e devidamente **aprovada**.

Comment: impressionante cara vlw uma duvida eu tentei adicionar valor manualmente no algoritmo é deu erro pode me explicar pq ?

Comment: Essa é a entrada padrão para todos os problemas da obi ? desculpe sou iniciante na progamação.

Comment: poderia comentar os erros do meu codigo me ajudaria muito se não for muito incômodo.

Comment: Não entendir esse comando p = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

Comment: Amigo esta entra é apenas uma de dezenas de entradas possíveis da OBI. Esta entrada é a que funciona nesta questão. Na primeiro input você deve inserir um valor - exemplo  5 - e pressionar ENTER. No segundo input, você deve digitar todos os 5 valores, na mesma linha e separados por um só espaço e pressionar ENTER.

Comment: A linha de comandos -  p = [int(i) for i in input().split()] - nada mais é do que um List Comprehension. Esta linha de código serve para capturar mais de um valor por linha.

Comment: Pelo fato de seu código apresentar alguns erros, achei por bem remonta-lo, em vez de explicar todos os erros.